# Pagination in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

I am a noob in Zend and I would appreciate if you could help me to figure out how to use pagination in my case.

this is my [view](http://pastebin.com/6PJt59uW)
and this is my [controller](http://pastebin.com/BTHT1qYN)

I am using APIs to access my models.

I researched and read a lot about pagination in Zend but I had/have trouble implementing it.
Thank you for your willingness to help me out.

Comment: so where you have got problem.

Comment: I have a problem in a sense that I would like to use this Zend built in function but I'm having trouble implementing it in my case. I need a few basic guidelines.

Comment: ok, so { $resultq } variable returns data in array. right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your controller in line 36 write : (assuming $resultq is a valid zend_paginator param)

```
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($resultq);      
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->getRequest()->getParam('page')); // page number
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(20); // number of items to show per page

$this->view->paginator= $paginator;
```

now in your view you have to add pagination controls, either do it directly in the view or use a template (you can store templates in application/views/scripts/templates for example), here is an example of a pagination template : http://zendgeek.blogspot.com/2009/07/zend-pagination-example.html

then in your view you have to integrate the template (wherever you want the controls to appear) using:

```
 <?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator, 'Sliding', 'templates/pagination.phtml'); ?>
```

and instead of using `<?php foreach ($this->basicBwDetails as $result): ?>` use `<?php foreach ($this->paginator as $result): ?>`